# SelectedIndexChanged event of DropDownList is not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net

`ASPX FILE`  contain `DropDown` as Follows:

```
< asp:DropDownList ID="drpDist" runat="server" CssClass="dropDownStyle" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpDist_SelectedIndexChanged" TabIndex="6">
```

In `ASPX.CS FILE`

```
protected void drpDist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Please Help me.I can't get why it is not working.

Comment: you need to enable the autopostback property and set it to true, by default its false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `AutoPostBack="True"` property. This will make the page to postback automatically hence firing your event.

Answer (score 3):

Use Property

`AutoPostBack="True"`

Answer (score 3):

you need to set [`AutoPostBack="true"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpDist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
```

when you set that property as true, a postback to the server automatically occurs whenever the user changes the selection of the list

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"`

```
< asp:DropDownList ID="drpDist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="dropDownStyle" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpDist_SelectedIndexChanged" TabIndex="6">
```